# PHP Checking if the current date is before or after a set date

Tags: php

Im pulling a date from a database which is formatted like dd-mm-YYYY.

What I want to do is check the current date;

- if the current date is before the date coming from the database then it needs to print the database date
- if its after then it needs to print 'go ahead'.
  Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you sure you can't do this *in* the database, before the formatting and re-parsing complicates it needlessly?

Comment: I've added an SQL only solution to prove @Piskvor's point

Answer (score 127, accepted):

```
if( strtotime($database_date) > strtotime('now') ) {
...
```

Comment: Any particular reason you prefer `strtotime('now')` over `time()` ?

Comment: @ChrisR I think in this particular case it makes the code a bit clearer since I'm already using strtotime to convert the database date. It's mostly just a personal preference, time() would work just as well.

Comment: @AlexBarker in what way? Seems to work 5.3 - current for sure. https://3v4l.org/TNSNN

Comment: This isn't _ideal_ for all use-cases. If you compare the `strtotime` of the **same** date, and say `$database_date` is just `01-01-2018`, the `'now'` time is going to be _after_ it because it includes the time. You'd use something like `strtotime(date('Ymd'))` to get around that.

Answer (score 44):

Here's a list of all possible checks for …

> *"Did a date pass?"*

#### Possible ways to obtain the value

```
$date = strtotime( $date );

$date > date( "U" )
$date > mktime( 0, 0, 0 )
$date > strtotime( 'now' )
$date > time()
$date > abs( intval( $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] ) )
```

#### Performance Test Result (PHP 5.4.7)

I did some performance test on 1.000.000 iterations and calculated the average – Ordered fastest to slowest.

```
+---------------------+---------------+
|        method       |     time      |
+---------------------+---------------+
|        time()       | 0.0000006732  |
|       $_SERVER      | 0.0000009131  |
|      date("U")      | 0.0000028951  |
|     mktime(0,0,0)   | 0.000003906   |
|   strtotime("now")  | 0.0000045032  |
| new DateTime("now") | 0.0000053365  |
+---------------------+---------------+
```

**ProTip:** You can easily remember what's fastest by simply looking at the length of the function. The longer, the slower the function is.

#### Performance Test Setup

The following loop was run for each of the above mentioned possibilities. I converted the values to non-scientific notation for easier readability.

```
$loops = 1000000;
$start = microtime( true );
for ( $i = 0; $i < $loops; $i++ )
    date( "U" );
printf(
    '|    date("U")     | %s  |'."\n",
    rtrim( sprintf( '%.10F', ( microtime( true ) - $start ) / $loops ), '0' )
);
```

### Conclusion

`time()` still seems to be the fastest.

Comment: Forgot to mention that this was run with PHP 5.4.7

Answer (score 7):

I wanted to set a specific date so have used this to do stuff before 2nd December 2013

```
if(mktime(0,0,0,12,2,2013) > strtotime('now')) {
    // do stuff
}
```

The `0,0,0` is midnight, the `12` is the month, the `2` is the day and the `2013` is the year.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a generic way of doing this via MySQL, you could simply use a `SELECT` statement, and add the `WHERE` clause to it.

This will grab all fields for all rows, where the date stored in field "date" is before "now".

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

Personally, I found this method to be more gentle on newbies in MySQL, since it uses the standard SELECT statement with WHERE to fetch the results. Obviously, you could grab only the fields relevant if you wanted to, by listing them instead of using a wildcard (*).

Answer (score 3):

I have used this one and it served the purpose:

```
if ($date < date("Y-m-d")) {
    echo "Date is in the past";
}
```

BR

Answer (score 2):

`if (strtotime($date) > mktime(0,0,0))` should do the job.

Comment: +1 `mktime()` wouldn't be my choice, but good job being mindful of *midnight*.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(strtotime($row['database_date']) > strtotime('now')) echo $row['database_date'];
else echo date("d-m-Y");
```

No need to check the hours because if they are on the same day it will show the same date either way...

Comment: You are incorrect. Hours do play into a UNIX timestamp comparison and your check would always fail for the current date. Use `strtotime('midnight')` to correct your code.

Comment: its a moot point is what I was saying, because if I display the database date or todays date, they are going to be the same.  But yes, you are correct if you needed to wait until tomorrow to say go ahead, I assumed that you can 'go ahead' on today's date, not tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(strtotime($db_date) > time()) {
  echo $db_date;
} else {
  echo 'go ahead';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert any date to unix timestamp and compare.

Comment: caveat: unix timestamp is only defined for dates between the years 1901 and 2038 (and yes, people are getting bitten by this already: today+30 years is beyond that; insurance or mortgage, anyone?).

Comment: @Piskvor - good point. the next millennium bug paranoia! unless the 2012 is the end of the world :-)

Comment: time goes fast. 16 years to go

Answer (score 0):

a MySQL-only solution would be something like this:

```
SELECT IF (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`field`) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), `field`,'GO AHEAD') as `yourdate`
FROM `table`
```