# Check if date is before or after a certain date in the same month

Tags: php

I am developing a web app using PHP (Codeigniter).
When a user makes a request for a certain resource in the app I need to check if todays date is before or after the 25th of this month. How can I do this? I do not know how to do it.

Comment: There've been A LOT of questions about PHP dates. If you google it, you will get answer in first 2 pages.

Comment: @Donut haters gonna hate, this site is for helping not hating

Comment: @Petah This site is not for duplicates. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close

Comment: @Donut, then close vote, and point out duplicates, don't hate.

Comment: Similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149569/php-checking-if-the-current-date-is-before-or-after-a-set-date http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475019/php-check-if-current-time-is-before-specified-time

Answer (score 3):

This should do it...

```
if ( date('j') < 25 ) {
    // date before 25th
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `date` function with the `j` format type for that

```
if (date('j') > 25) {
    // It is after the 25th
} elseif (date('j') < 25) {
    // It is before the 25th
} else {
    // It is the 25th
}
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for more info